# Importar classe que não esteja dentro de um projeto no eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de importar e instanciar um objeto de uma classe que esteja, por exemplo, dentro de uma pasta nos meus arquivos e não em um projeto dentro do eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

De certa foram é possível sim.

Existem ao menos 3 opções:

A mais simples é:

Selecione o projeto > Properties > Java Build Path > Aba Libraries > Clique em Add External Class Folder > Selecione pasta.

Comment: Exatamente isso, mas o que eu estava precisando era de uma maneira de fazer essa importação sem precisar usar o wizard, clicando e selecionando. Fazer de uma forma automática pelo código

Comment: Você pode editar o .classpath depois de criado o projeto. Não usa o wizard, mas não é elegante.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder instanciar um objeto desta classe, ela precisa:

1. Ser uma classe do seu projeto ou
2. Estar na lista de dependências do seu projeto

Comment: Além da forma que citei abaixo, pode-se ainda usar Classpath do eclipse e Linkar com uma pasta externa.